# Solid CP Reset password

Tags: sql-server, linux, iis

i have VPS and installed Solid CP . I forgot my login password to control panel and when I tried to reset my password with the link in login page , it didn't send any reset password link to my email . its valid mail and i set it up way before when I installed Solid CP .

is there any way to reset my password from the server it self ?
like from MS SQL or main files ?

reset password link

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the SolidCP Installer on the machine.

Once inside the installer select Enterprise Server then Setting. As you go through the wizard, it will offer to reset the password.

[image]